# SQL: Select data when one row of differents table are equal > 1 times

Tags: sql

I have three tables: (This is a example)

- animal (id, type, legs, dni)
- ciudad (id, name, people, province, dni)
- persona (dni, name, age, phone, email)

The data for example is this:

**Animal**

```
+---+------+---+-----------+
| 1 | gato | 4 | 48063044C |
| 2 | gato | 4 | 48063044C |
| 3 | gato | 4 | 48063055D |
| 4 | gato | 4 | 48063055D |
+---+------+---+-----------+
```

**Ciudad**

```
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 1 | barcelona | 10000 | barcelona | 48063044C |
| 2 | madrid    | 10000 | madrid    | 48063055D |
+---+-----------+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Persona**

```
+-----------+--------+----+-----------+------------------+
| 48063044C | lluis  | 21 | 934444444 | lluis@gmail.com  |
| 48063055D | albert | 30 | 935555555 | albert@gmail.com |
+-----------+--------+----+-----------+------------------+
```

I want to make a Query where I select some data of the persons who have **more than 1** animal. (The field DNI in table animal it's the DNI of the owner).

I have this:

```
SELECT p.dni as 'DNI', p.nombre as 'Nombre', p.edad as 'Edad',
       p.telefono as 'Telefono', p.email as 'Email',
       (SELECT c.nombre FROM ciudad c WHERE c.dni = p.dni) as 'Nombre ciudad'
FROM persona p 
INNER JOIN animal a ON a.dni = p.dni
HAVING COUNT(a.dni = p.dni) > 1
```

And I only get this data:

```
+-----------+-------+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
| 48063044C | lluis | 21 | 934444444 | lluis@gmail.com | barcelona |
+-----------+-------+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Correct me if wrong, but I think this doesn't work correctly. I should get the data of the other person, because they have two animals too.

I know the relation with DNI it's not good but it's only to make the example.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (`as 'DNI'` is invalid standard SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT(p.dni)` instead of `COUNT(a.dni = p.dni)`. Also you can convert the subquery to a join especially since you're already joining the animals table.

Try this:

```
SELECT p.dni AS 'DNI', p.nombre AS 'Nombre', p.edad AS 'Edad', p.telefono AS 'Telefono',
       p.email AS 'Email', c.nombre AS 'Nombre ciudad'
FROM persona p 
INNER JOIN animal a ON a.dni = p.dni
LEFT JOIN ciudad c ON c.dni = p.dni
GROUP BY p.dni
HAVING COUNT(a.dni) > 1
```

Comment: What makes the difference it's the `GROUP BY`, Thanks a lot ;) You think it's better to make JOIN than subquery? Thanks again. I will try something more :)

Comment: In general, yes it is better to use joins than subqueries. Database engines should be able to optimize both, but some engines may optimize joins better than subqueries. Also it is generally easier to read, but that's a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

According to your need following query will work, and give you required results.
following is postgresql query

```
WITH animal AS (
SELECT 1::int AS id, 'gato'::varchar AS type, 4::int AS legs, '48063044C'::varchar AS dni
UNION ALL
SELECT 2::int AS id, 'gato'::varchar AS type, 4::int AS legs, '48063044C'::varchar AS dni
UNION ALL
SELECT 3::int AS id, 'gato'::varchar AS type, 4::int AS legs, '48063055D'::varchar AS dni
UNION ALL
SELECT 4::int AS id, 'gato'::varchar AS type, 4::int AS legs, '48063055D'::varchar AS dni
),
ciudad AS (
SELECT 1::int AS id, 'barcelona'::varchar AS name, 10000::int AS people, 'barcelona'::varchar AS province, '48063044C'::varchar AS dni
UNION ALL
SELECT 2::int AS id, 'madrid'::varchar AS name, 10000::int AS people, 'madrid'::varchar AS province, '48063055D'::varchar AS dni
),
persona AS (
SELECT '48063044C'::varchar AS dni, 'lluis'::varchar AS name, 21::int AS age, '934444444'::varchar AS phone, 'lluis@gmail.com'::varchar AS email
UNION ALL
SELECT '48063055D'::varchar AS dni, 'albert'::varchar AS name, 30::int AS age, '935555555'::varchar AS phone, 'albert@gmail.com'::varchar AS email
)
SELECT 
      p.dni AS DNI,
      p.name AS Nombre,
      p.age AS Edad,
      p.phone AS Telefono,
      p.email AS Email,
      c.name AS Nombre_ciudad
FROM 
    persona p 
    INNER JOIN animal a ON (a.dni = p.dni)
    LEFT JOIN ciudad c ON (c.dni = p.dni)
GROUP BY 
    p.dni,p.name,p.age,p.phone,p.email,c.name
HAVING 
    COUNT(a.dni) > 1
```